Segment an image collection in GEE using a sample file (vector or raster) from rsgislib, python
I'm trying to segment a Sentinel image collection in GEE using a .tif image that I observed from rsgislib segmentation using Python.
It's worth to mention that the output is .kea and I converted it to .tif. I also can export
vectors with format .gpkg.
Is there any solution to segment images based on my result, or do I just need to back to  .SNIC() ?
